# How can I make a button load an iFrame content

Tags: html

I'm using the same page for all my website where only the body content changes, instead of using links I wanna use buttons to load the page content.
Here's my main html page

```
<button id="b1"> button 1</button>
<button id="b2"> button 2</button>
<div> <iframe id="iFrame"></iframe> </div>
```

I want button1 and button2 to load 2 different pages page1 and page2 when clicked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use javascript.
Your html code should be this.

```
<button id="b1" onClick="b1()"> button 1</button>
<button id="b2" onClick="b2()"> button 2</button>
<div> <iframe id="iFrame"></iframe> </div>
```

Your javascript code should be this. Remember to replace the values of the iframe.src with the file names you want.

```
<script>
var iframe=document.getElementById("iFrame");
function b1() {
iframe.src = "page1.html";
}
function b2() {
iframe.src = "page2.html";
}
</script>
```

Comment: I think I have some issues with my javascript (don't know how maybe I need to load some libraries)  but the clicking the buttons doesn't do anything

Comment: Can you please post the javascript too? Please.

Comment: <button id="b1" onClick="b1()">button 1</button>
    <button id="b2" onClick="b2()">button 2</button>

    <div> <iframe id="iFrame"></iframe></div>

   <script>
 var iframe=document.getElementById("iFrame");
 function b1(){
  iframe.scr="home.html";
 }
 function b2(){
  iframe.scr="theme.html";
 }
   </script>

Comment: It is a small mistake of yours. You had typed iframe.scr in both the functions. Instead of it you need to type iframe.src

Comment: Exactly, but I didn't know because the same solution didn't work (no typing mistakes were there)  so I just didn't bother to correct

Comment: Inline event handlers shouldn't be used. Use `addEventListener()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would approach this:

```js
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-url]'), elem => {
  elem.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    iFrame.src = this.dataset.url
  })
})
```

```css
[data-url]::after {
  content: attr(data-url)
}

#iFrame { /* this is for demo purposes only */
  min-height: 400px;
  width: 1024px;
}
```

```html
<button data-url="https://connexo.de"></button>
<button data-url="https://connexo.de/kontakt.php"></button>
<div> <iframe id="iFrame"></iframe> </div>
```

If you need details on any part of this, let me know exactly what is unclear to you.

Note that the above code snippet is using an Arrow function which is part of ECMAScript 6 (the official name for Javascript is ECMAScript).

This is the ES5 version which supposedly will work in your Dreamweaver:

```js
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-url]'), function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    iFrame.src = this.dataset.url
  })
})
```

```css
[data-url]::after {
  content: attr(data-url)
}

#iFrame { /* this is for demo purposes only */
  min-height: 400px;
  width: 1024px;
}
```

```html
<button data-url="https://connexo.de"></button>
<button data-url="https://connexo.de/kontakt.php"></button>
<div> <iframe id="iFrame"></iframe> </div>
```

And this is the HTML only version which you can copy/paste into your HTML file:

```html
<style type=text/css>
  [data-url]::after {
    content: attr(data-url)
  }
  
  #iFrame {
    /* this is for demo purposes only */
    min-height: 400px;
    width: 1024px;
  }
</style>

<button data-url="https://connexo.de"></button>
<button data-url="https://connexo.de/kontakt.php"></button>
<div> <iframe id="iFrame"></iframe> </div>

<script>
  /* it is important you put the script part after the HTML with the buttons */
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-url]'), function(elem) {
    elem.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      iFrame.src = this.dataset.url
    })
  })
</script>
```

Comment: I got some errors (don't really know how to correct them since I'm not that used to coding in html)  I don't know how to define elem

Comment: You don't need to define `elem`, it's just the name of the parameter that automatically gets passed into each iteration of `forEach`. What errors exactly are you getting?

Comment: I'm using dream weaver, it just says "there is a syntax error on line" . The code doesn't show any errors when I remove elem => {
  elem.addEventListener('click', function(e)

Comment: Run your code in Chrome, not Dreamweaver. Dreamweaver is a good editor for visually designing the basic stuff. You need to configure the Javascript language level to "ES6".

Comment: Same it doesn't load the page when clicked

Comment: Have you also adjusted the HTML?

Comment: You mean adding <script> and my own pages names instead of "https//connexo.de"?

Comment: Do I add this to my css [data-url]::after {
  content: attr(data-url)
}

#iFrame { /* this is for demo purposes only */
  min-height: 400px;
  width: 1024px;
} or is it not necessary? or is it not even css?

Comment: I added a third code snippet where I've put everything into the HTML.

Comment: Is there a way to make page1 the default page?

Comment: `<iframe id="iFrame" src="page1.html"></iframe>`. Why did you accept the other answer over this?

Answer (score 0):

This is my second answer in this question. You can remove the javascript portion and use this html code only.

```html
<button id="b1" onClick="document.getElementById('iFrame').src = 'page1.html'"> button 1</button>
<button id="b2" onClick="document.getElementById('iFrame').src = 'page2.html'"> button 2</button>
<div> <iframe id="iFrame"></iframe> </div>
```